# How to get a Scanner to ignore words between a certain pattern

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I want to read input from a file using a scanner, but I want the scanner to ignore everything inside (* ....... *). How do I do this? I'm taking integers and adding them to an array list, but if there are integers inside the text I want to ignore it adds those too.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> readNumbers(Scanner sc) 
    {
        // TODO Implement readNumbers
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
               String temp = sc.next();
               list.add(Integer.parseInt(temp));
             }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        } 
        return list;
    }
```

Here's an example line of the text file

(* 21 Alabama Population in 2013 *)      4802740

I would add 21 and 4802740 to my array list. 
I thought about using 
   sc.usedelimiter("(*");
   sc.usedelimiter("*)");
But I just can't seem to get it to work. 
Thanks!

Comment: all your input has same pattern? so (* 25 Los Angles in 2013 *) 4802743 is right?

Comment: Can there be any `*` in `(*...*)` part beside the ones at start or end?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "I would add 21 and 4802740 to my array list", because it looks like `21` should be included in result while `2013` not. If that so can you give us any logic which will explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may be looking for something like

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\(\\*[^*]*\\*\\)|\\s+");
```

This regular expression `\\(\\*[^*]*\\*\\)` represents part which

- `\\(\\*` - starts with `(*`,
- `\\*\\)` - ends with `*)`
- `[^*]*` - and have zero or more non `*` characters inside.

I also added `|\\s+` to allow one or more spaces be delimiter (this delimiter is used by scanners by default).

---

BTW using try-catch as main part of control flow is generally considered as wrong. Instead you should change your code to something like

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(sc.nextInt());
    } else {
        //consume data you are not interested in 
        //so Scanner could move on to next tokens
        sc.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: like it but it just extract 4802740

Comment: @KickButtowski which seems to be exactly what OP wants "*I want the scanner to ignore everything inside ( * ....... * ).*"

Comment: @KickButtowski I suspect hat "*I would add 21 and 4802740 to my array list.*" means that currently (not working) code works this way, not that OP wants to have this results.

Comment: oh k I thought it wants 21 too :)

Comment: @KickButtowski I am not saying that I am sure I am right, it is only my suspicion. OP would need to tell us more about desired result and explain if `21` should be in result. If so then why `2013` shouldn't.

Comment: If it is the case why not do the simple split?

Comment: `split` is an option, but at the same time we could also use `replaceAll` to remove unwanted areas and then use Scanner on cleared data. OP asked for Scanner solution so I gave it. I also like Scanner over `split` or `replaceAll` because of `hasNextInt` method which will let us avoid heavy `try-catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the "(* string *)" before reading next int:

```
try
{
    try {
        sc.skip("\\s*\\(\\*[^*]*\\*\\)");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    }
    String temp = sc.next();
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(temp));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: like it but it just extract 4802740

Comment: This will skip "Any whitespace, and then (* ... *)" before trying to parse the next token.